# Where can I find earthquake resistant school design?

Tags: africa, usaidopen

I am looking for earthquake resistant designs for school construction in Africa. Ideally, including blueprints.

Comment: What building materials do you have available or plan to use?

Comment: Are you looking for data on school buildings in Africa that were built using earthquake-resistant design guidelines? Or are you looking for actual guidelines or standards?

Comment: [Meta question](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/369/is-asking-for-a-design-open-data-i-e-on-topic?noredirect=1#comment433_369) about this one

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why schools in Africa should be designed in any different way than buildings for housing people for other purposes elsewhere. There might be constraints to do with cost, availability of skilled labour, and building materials available, but such constraints apply everywhere.

Other deciding factors might include risk of earthquake, and likely magnitude of earthquakes, which will vary depending on location, Africa is huge, so certainly there won't be a one size fits all solution, (well you could build structures to withstand magnitude 9+ earthquakes in areas with very low earthquake risk, which would be a massive waste of money and resources).

A good resource for addressing risk of earthquake in Africa is [Earthquake Risk in Africa: Modified Mercalli Scale, December 2007](http://reliefweb.int/map/ethiopia/earthquake-risk-africa-modified-mercalli-scale-december-2007) which includes a PDF

One place to start looking for guidance on building design would be the US Federal Emergency Management Agency (FEMA) pages on [Earthquake Publications: Building Codes and Seismic Rehabilitation](https://www.fema.gov/earthquake-publications-building-codes-and-seismic-rehabilitation)